# What are the best places to eat and have fun in Aruba?

Tags: budget, food-and-drink, recommendations, aruba

I'm going to **Aruba** in December and I'd like to know the best place to eat considering the relationship price/quality.

I'd also would like to know what other fun activities you recommend (besides going to the beach, watersports, snorkeling, etc) Any other tip about this island would also be very welcome!

Comment: Sorry @cch I don't want to put you off our site when you've just arrived, but if you check the FAQ, Stack Exchange is not meant for subjective questions or questions which should be answered with a list. And the people behind Stack Exchange have a particular dislike for shopping questions. If you can make a really specific question that's likely to have a single right answer then we can do our best to find that answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I got the subjective questions part and edited the question, but I don't get why shopping questions are bad, aren´t they part of traveling or things to do while you are traveling?

Comment: Jeff Atwood, one of the guys behind Stack Exchange wrote a famous blog post about the shopping issue about a year ago: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Thanks! Read it, and edited the question again. I believe is better now.

Comment: Aruba is REALLY Expensive! Only go there to enjoy the beautiful beaches. Bring everything you need and enjoy the white sand and clear waters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, I've not been there, but I'll try and say  what I would do, as your food methodology seems to echo mine :)

The [Aruba Ostrich Farm](http://www.arubaostrichfarm.com/) would be my first stop if you've not tried Ostrich meat.  Dried, sliced, or in a burger, it's a delicious meat.

Snorkelling sounds pretty great there, and for once you're not left out with wrecks that only scuba divers can get to (I can't scuba dive, so I'm jealous).  There are many snorkel tours, and the one that sounds interesting to me is the Antillla Shipwreck. It is the remains of a scuttled 400-foot German cargo ship that was anchored off of Aruba during WW2. It was thought that this ship was supplying German U-Boats in the Caribbean and after Holland was invaded in 1940, the captain was given notice to surrender the ship. Instead of surrendering the ship to the Dutch Marines the captain sunk the ship by blowing up the boilers.

I'd also check out the Arikok National Park - The park consists of lava formations, a quartz diorite formation and a limestone formation extending inward from the coastline.

If you enjoy spelunking, there's the Guadirkiri Caves to check out as well!

Boca Catalina beach is near the aforementioned wreck, has more snorkelling options and great white sandy beaches.

Most chains are there (Subway, BK, Pizza Hut and the rest) but I'd be trying to hunt out the local foods - the most unusual sounding being Iguana soup! Yum!

And if you drink, you're in Aruba, please don't forget to try some Jamaican rum!