# Shopping in Los Angeles

Tags: los-angeles, shopping

After returning from a cruise to Hawaii, we will be spending a single day in Los Angeles. We will already have spent a couple of days there before the cruise, so the plan is to just spend that day shopping.

We will not have a car, so we expect to make do with taxis and/or shuttles.

What are our best options? We were thinking a mall with a nearby hotel. Bonus points if it is fairly close to LAX. We would like to shop for "normal" clothes (i.e. not super-expensive designer brands), consumer electronics and so on, so I guess any medium/large mall would do. Any shop with cake decorating equipment (Michaels or similar) would also be super.

I have been looking at South Coast Plaza and Glendale Galleria, but they seem to be a bit far away from LAX. Westfield Culver City seemed somewhat closer, but according to Yelp it is a bit "ghetto" (whatever that means).

Comment: Are you planning to buy anything in particular or would any mega mall do?

Comment: Hi @Rasmus Faber.  As per our [faq], I'm sorry, but for reasons linked to in the FAQ, we avoid having shopping questions.  Please feel free to ask other questions about Los Angeles, cruises, or Hawaii, but just not shopping - sorry!

Comment: @Mark Mayo: Unless I totally misread the FAQ, the "shopping related"-questions that are not allowed are "which backpack should I buy", "what is the best laptop for traveling" etc., not "where should I shop in a foreign country".

Comment: @RasmusFaber - sorry, I should have been more specific.  You're right in that 'which backpack' is the problem in the FAQ, and I admit I skim read and merely thought of a similar question we closed until reword -  http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3485/101 - Stackexchange is historically unfond of shopping questions.  However, even given that, to ask where to shop in a city (Los Angeles) that covers 500 square miles is rather vague.  If you could say what you're after - sports, souvenir, designer clothes etc, we could see it as being possible to reopen.  Thanks for the polite query.

Comment: @Peter Hahndorf: Any mega mall would do. We are from Denmark and would like to shop "normal" clothes, consumer electronics and so on.

Comment: For the Stack Exchange view on shopping please read this blog entry by Jeff Atwood: **[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page '[Malls and Shopping Centers - LAX Area](http://www.latourist.com/index.php?page=shopping-center-links-lax)' has various place close to LAX, the same site also [has lists](http://www.latourist.com/index.php?page=shopping-center-links) for other areas of LA.

I haven't been to any of the ones around LAX, I guess they are pretty generic but maybe good enough for your needs. If you want to escape the malls, [Third Street Promenade](http://www.thirdstreetpromenade.com) in Santa Monica is a nice enough pedestrian area, but it's a bit further away, but the beach is really close.

Comment: Thank you very much. We have booked a hotel in Santa Monica - it looks great.